# Making a solution file without using visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, solution

I'm building a program which generates a lot of code files (cpp,h,hpp files).
using a "Generate" button triggers the making of the new files, I want to add a another functionality, I also want the "Generate" button to make a sulotion(for visual studio) after it done generating the files with the right settings, so the users wont have to deal with it. 
so the user clicks "Generate", new files are generated and he can also open the whole project in visual studio, fixed in the right order.

how can I do that?

Comment: Open up some solution and project files with notepad. examine them. try to understand them. finally create your own!

Comment: @FarhanAnam Reverse engineering is sometimes not wise and in this case not necessary, Microsoft already provides an API for that.  See answer below

Answer (score 4):

You can take a leaf out of the custom *Visual Studio Project System* examples and use the  **Microsoft.Build.Construction** namespace of the **Microsoft.Build.dll** assembly.

MSDN:

> The Microsoft.Build namespaces contain types that provide programmatic access to, and control of, the MSBuild engine.

[ProjectRootElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) is the primary class used to add files to and create your solution progmatically.

> Represents an MSBuild project, a targets file, or any other file that conforms to MSBuild project file schema. This class and its related classes allow a complete MSBuild project or targets file to be read and written. [Tell me more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

For example, to start off your solution you might:

```
var project = ProjectRootElement.Create();

project.DefaultTargets = "Build";
project.ToolsVersion = "4.0";
```

...to add files you might do something like:

```
foreach (var unescapedFile in allFiles)
{
    var file = ProjectCollection.Escape(unescapedFile);
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
    var fileType = "Content";   
    folders.Add(Path.GetDirectoryName(file));    
    var item = project.AddItem(fileType, file);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

...finalise the solution with:

```
var imports = project.AddPropertyGroup();
imports.AddProperty("VisualStudioVersion", "10.0")
       .Condition = " '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' ";

(customization ?? DefaultProjectCustomization.Instance).Process(
                                                                project,
    new Dictionary<string, ProjectPropertyGroupElement>
    {
        {"Globals", globals},
        {"Imports", imports},
        {"Debug", debugGroup},
        {"Release", releaseGroup}
    }
    );
```

...and finally save the solution as XML with:

```
project.Save(writer);
```

### Templates

**EDIT**: Kudos to [millimoose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41655) for this suggestion in the comments below :)

If you want to load a "template" project file to be used a basis for new projects you may want to look into `ProjectRootElement.TryOpen()`.  It will return a `ProjectRootElement` that you could possibly use to modify and/or add new items too, saving the result as a new project.

e.g.

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("NewProject.csproj", false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var project = ProjectRootElement.TryOpen("my template.csproj");
    project.AddItem("Content", "miss piggy.png");
    project.Save(writer);
}
```

### Tell me more

- You can see a complete working example of how to programmatically generate a solution file in *[Microsoft's Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Projects)*.

Comment: I'd suggest maybe adding code to show how the OP can load some sort of existing solution file as template, if the MSBuild API doesn't do that. I seem to recall that actual VS solution files tend to have some cryptic, but possibly necessary boilerplate.

Comment: Useful for creating a PROJECT.... but I do not see you creating a SOLUTION (.sln)

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin look again.

Comment: @user585968 - I have, multiple times ove rthe past many months... how about something useful like a link....